# Are there any performance issues with allowing a hard drive to become full if the drive is effectively read-only?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, filesystems, raid

I'm fairly confident that the answer is "no issues," but I'm asking here in case there are any quirks that I'm failing to consider.

### Context

I have a large storage array (on a Linux system) that I'm currently in the process of restructuring, and part of it involves removing some old, slow, low-capacity disks (3TB and 4TB). I'm removing them from the array for performance reasons (they were cheap, slow drives to begin with), but I'd like to still take advantage of the capacity.

I've moved these old drives to a non-RAID configuration, and basically intend to use them to store "overflow" data that I'd like to keep around for convenience, but wouldn't care if it's lost.

### Question

These drives will act as cold storage for files that will rarely be written (if ever), and I'd like to maximize my capacity.

I plan to:

- Write zeroes to the drives.
- Format with a new filesystem.
- Use rsync to move files to each drive in one shot.

Would it cause any issues to fill a `3,907,018,532 KB` drive with ~`3,900,000,000 KB` of data, for example?

All the data will be moved onto a blank drive in one run, so there shouldn't be any fragmentation, and the only thing that would be written to the drive in the future is most likely just file access times, so there shouldn't be any thrashing from big writes. And I can't imagine there would be more than a couple simultaneous reads.

Are there any quirks in either the ext4 filesystem, the SATA spec, or wherever else that are going to cause issues *reading from* the drives if they're completely full?

Comment: One possible issue is the block size (eg a 10 byte file could take 4k on disk), so if you have lots of small files they would not fit unless you compress them together.

Comment: Alao, not sure there is any point in zeroing the drives if you are going to overwrite them. Maybe just zero put thr first 4k so the drive appears uninitialised?

Comment: @davidgo The zeroing is just the last step of my standard stress test script, and I just mentioned it incidentally. And most of the files are a gigabyte or more, so minimal space should be lost to underutilized sectors!